# Why to use list() method when inserting list into list in Python

Tags: python-3.x

So I wanted to insert list of 2 integers into a list of lists by using

```
coords = [110,50]
pos = [[100,50],[90,50],[80,50]]
pos.insert(0,coords)
```

It didn't work as I thought it would when used in **for** loop but I found the solution to this:

```
pos.insert(0,list(coords))
```

Now this  inserts **coords** at the beginning of my **pos** list, but I am wondering why I have to use the list() method when **coords** is already a list itself. This is a whole example code:

```
coords = [100,50]
pos1 = [[100,50],[90,50],[80,50]]
pos2 = [[100,50],[90,50],[80,50]]
for i in range(5):
    print(i+1)
    coords[0] += 10

    pos1.insert(0,coords)
    print ('Pos1: ',pos1)

    pos2.insert(0,list(coords))
    print ('Pos2: ',pos2)
```

As it can be noticed in output, **pos1** and **pos2** lists are quite different.

```
1
Pos1:  [[110, 50], [100, 50], [90, 50], [80, 50]]
Pos2:  [[110, 50], [100, 50], [90, 50], [80, 50]]
2
Pos1:  [[120, 50], [120, 50], [100, 50], [90, 50], [80, 50]]
Pos2:  [[120, 50], [110, 50], [100, 50], [90, 50], [80, 50]]
3
Pos1:  [[130, 50], [130, 50], [130, 50], [100, 50], [90, 50], [80, 50]]
Pos2:  [[130, 50], [120, 50], [110, 50], [100, 50], [90, 50], [80, 50]]
4
Pos1:  [[140, 50], [140, 50], [140, 50], [140, 50], [100, 50], [90, 50], [80, 50]]
Pos2:  [[140, 50], [130, 50], [120, 50], [110, 50], [100, 50], [90, 50], [80, 50]]
5
Pos1:  [[150, 50], [150, 50], [150, 50], [150, 50], [150, 50], [100, 50], [90, 50], [80, 50]]
Pos2:  [[150, 50], [140, 50], [130, 50], [120, 50], [110, 50], [100, 50], [90, 50], [80, 50]]
```

Can anyone please explain what is the difference when inserting **coords** and **list(coords)**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inserting coords works just fine -- but you are inserting *the same list object* each time. So your loop just adds a number of references to the same list, and when you do `coords[0] += 10` then that list changes, and you see the change reflected everywhere in pos1.

Using `list(coords)` makes a **copy** of coords, so then it's a new list containing the same values, and changing the original doesn't change the copy.

`coords[:]` is also a popular way of making a copy of a list.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I couldn't figure it out but now it makes sense.